# Execute query in Access VB

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table in Access that I am willing out through an 'order form',
so for example at some point it might have 8 items of orders (1 x soft drink = 2$, 3 x coffee = 10$, etc).

I want to do a form to display all the rows from the table 'orders' and then sum their value to get the total.  How do I do that?

I am used to working in PHP, where I could loop over all the records in the table, and then sum their total. How can I do that in VBA?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? (And concerning the second part of the question: Since it deals with a different topic, you should open up a seperate question.)

Comment: stupid me, i just noticed the mistaked, i missed a letter, i will re-edit the question to be my 2nd one only! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a subform, and have the recordset behind that subform be a GROUP BY query that will just return one record with your totals.

Comment: how exactly do you do a subform? i actually have no idea how to do any of those steps, am new to access..any chance u can detail it out plz?

Comment: If you know how to add a button to a form, adding a subform is similar.  First, create a new form and as the recordset you will put this GROUP BY query.  Subforms are usually named something like subMyFormName or sfrmMyFormName just so you'll know it's a subform and not a parent form.  Then drag and drop the subform object from the toolbox (just like you're adding a button or a textbox) onto your first form (referred to as the Parent), and it will ask you if you have already created the subform.  Pick the form you created above and it will become a subform (or Child) of the Parent form.